# YouTube Analytics API : 403 Forbidden Error returns Earnings Report

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I have a CMS account an I'm trying to get earnings data from content owners report on Analytics API using OAuth 2.0 . Whenever I'm trying to do this through my website, I get the following error ;

Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=contentOwner%3D%3DContentOwnerID&start-date=2005-01-01&end-date=2015-11-26&metrics=views%2Cearnings%2Clikes%2Cdislikes%2Cshares%2Ccomments&dimensions=30DayTotals&filters=channel%3D%3DChannel_ID: (403) Forbidden

I'm doing the same thing on [TRY IT](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query) page and it works fine.

I'm thinking that I'm having issues with authenticating my domain. What do you think is the problem? How can I solve this issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem..

Whoever will have this issue, please use the CMS user's OAuth 2.0 credentials instead of using channel credentials..

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you did to solve this? what do you mean by CMS user's OAuth 2.0? do you mean the google api OAuth2.0 key and client id!

Comment: @iwocan what CMS user stands for?

Answer (score 1):

403 means nobody has access to a page. As you noticed, you may have access to a similar page, but not to this one. It is not a matter of authentication. Authentication problems give a status 401 (meaning it can be fixed by adding proper authentication); 403 cannot be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. If this is not something about authorization, do you think that there's an issue with my codes ?